# Adding custom status page to Jenkins instance

Tags: rest, jenkins

I want to use the `REST API` that comes with `Jenkins` to generate a status page which shows all my projects, the environments they're currently deployed to, latest build versions etc.

Jenkins provides a nice REST API to expose this info however consuming the service is limited by cross domain restrictions. I have looked briefly at creating a CORS filter for my Jenkins instance but its overkill for what I'm trying to achieve.

Can someone tell me if its possible to modify my Jenkins WAR (instance) and add some HTML which i can then modify to call the RESTful endpoints? Ideally i want something whereby i can simply navigate to `http://myjenkins/project-status` and see the required information.

Comment: You are probably better asking somewhere specifically for jenkins. Still, you might want to look at making a custom plugin.

Comment: There is a [Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin) which acts on remote server. Maybe you can look in source code for that, to determine how they work around cross domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your status page has some Javascript executing XMLHttpRequests. You could drop your status page files into $JENKINS_HOME/userContent directory on the master. This way they are served by Jenkins and should be able to access Jenkins REST APIs.